# Pandas panel: Copy versus view

Tags: python, pandas

So basically, if I want to change data in the *original df*, I always have to use `.loc[]`. But consider the following

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> from scipy import random
>>> from numpy import arange

>>> T, N = 4, 5
>>> TIndex = arange(0, T)
>>> FIndex = arange(0, N)

>>> wp = pd.Panel(items=['A', 'w', 'l', 'a', 'x', 'X', 'd', 'profit'],
...               major_axis=TIndex, minor_axis=FIndex)
>>> wp.loc['a', 0, 0] = 0 
>>> df = wp.loc[0, 'a']
>>> df.loc[0, 'a'] = 'test'
>>> df.loc[0, 'a']
Out[379]: 'test'
>>> wp.loc['a', 0, 0]
Out[380]: 0
```

What am I doing wrong?

Also, no `SettingWithCopyWarning` has been thrown. I typically get these when I do these mistakes on dataframe level. This is highly irritating.

Comment: What are `T` and `N`?  It is best to provide an example that is self-contained, if possible.

Comment: Some positive integers. I added some values there .)

Comment: What version are you using? Your example throws a KeyError on `df = wp.loc[0, 'a']` for me. 0 isn't in your items.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I could modify both the DataFrame and the original Panel by selecting by label in the call to `loc`.  The documentation says that `loc` is [strictly limited to labels](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html), so I am not sure the code you have posted can work at all: I got a `KeyError: 'the label [0] is not in the [items]'` when pasting the example into an IPython console (?).

Instead of

```py
df = wp.loc[0, 'a']
```

do

```py
df = wp.loc['a']
```

Then modify with `iloc` and integer indexes:

```
In [3]: df
Out[3]:
    0   1   2   3   4
0   0 NaN NaN NaN NaN
1 NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
2 NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
3 NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN

[4 rows x 5 columns]

In [4]: df.iloc[0, 0] = 'test'

In [5]: df
Out[5]:
      0    1    2    3    4
0  test  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
1   NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
2   NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
3   NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN

[4 rows x 5 columns]

In [6]: wp.loc['a']
Out[6]:
      0    1    2    3    4
0  test  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
1   NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
2   NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
3   NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN

[4 rows x 5 columns]
```

Comment: So far great - I'll need to revise which part of my mess got lost while "dumbing" down the working example for SO. One follow-up if I may: what if `df` is not supposed to be a slice based on "item", but rather based on the major axes: Can I safely affect `df = wp.major_xs(0)` and the values will be set onto `wp`?

Comment: Sliced panels *can* give a view and should be so marked; this is a bug in that setting the viewed dataframe should raise a SettingWithCopy: https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/7184

Comment: @FooBar: as far as I can test it, no, you can't set values through the major axes.  Whether this is the correct behavior of Pandas or not, I am sorry to say that I don't know.

Comment: @FooBar as the documentation states you should *only* assign values using the multi-axis indexers, ``ix/iloc/loc``; slicing and selecting *may* work (and only in a single-dtyped case), but in general is not robust and should be avoided.

Comment: Jeff: So you say directly assigning `wp.loc[...] = foo` will work, but things of the sort `bar = wp.loc[...]; bar[...] = foo` will not necessarily and should be avoided?

Comment: FooBar, if you want to notify a user who is not the owner of the answer, or the OP, then you have to put an `@` before its username, like this: @Jeff . The reason I am not putting it in front of FooBar is because only one user may be notified at the same time.

Comment: @FooBar yep, ``bar=wp.loc[...]`` is a slice of the Panel (could be a panel, dataframe, series, or scalar depending on the args to ``.loc``). You should not assign to a slice ever (the whole reason to have the ``SettingWithCopy`` warning is to try to prevent this, but see here: http://pandas-docs.github.io/pandas-docs-travis/indexing.html#indexing-view-versus-copy; it is not always possible to even detect what the user is doing, it is simply a heuristic.